# Android - Como finalizar/terminar uma Activity?

Tags: java, android

Como fazer para fechar, finalizar, terminar uma `Activity`, depois que executar um método?

No meu projeto, eu tenho duas Activitys:

- MainActivity (Principal, Tela inicial)
- EditorActivity (Executa algumas tarefas simples)

Eu gostaria de finalizar ela, após chamar o ultimo método que conclui a tarefa dela e assim, ao finalizar, retornar para a Activity principal.

Comment: Utilize [finish](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish())

Comment: Eu não tinha lido na documentação. Estava tentando fazer da seguinte forma `MainActivity.class.finish;` ou `this.finish;`. De qualquer forma obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução no cometário do @valdeir-psr

Basta chamar o método finish() em dentro de qualquer método da activity. Outras formas redundantes seriam:

- `MainActivity.class.finish();`
- `this.finish();`
- `finish();` (A mais correta)

---

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()